# How to open a link in a new window in javascript and increase counter only on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to open a link at a specific counter value. For example if the counter value is multiple of 10 then http://www.google.com link opens up automatically in new tab and that counter increases only on button click. I am doing this in JavaScript.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

My code is -

```js
 $('button.counter').click(function myFunction() {
   var count = 1;

   while (count <= 60) {
     if (count == 10) {
       window.open("http://www.facebook.com/shawnikraghav");
     }
     count = count + 1;
   }
 });
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>Test Code</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  
</head>

<body>
  <script src="javascript.js"></script>
  <button class="counter" onClick="myFunction()">Click</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: First of all remove the value of `count` So it wouldn't be 1 every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define the counter variable outside the function call by click event. In you code, the counter will be initial to 1 each time you click.

And incase you want to check the counter value is multiple of 10, you should change the condition `(count%10) == 0`

```
var count = 1;
$('button.counter').click(function myFunction() 
{
    if((count%10 == 0) && (count < 60)) {
       window.open("http://www.facebook.com/shawnikraghav");
    } else {
       document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = count;
    }
    count = count + 1;
});
```

Comment: This totally works for me but like I tried an easy way and it is something like this but how to make it stop at 60?

`var count = 1;

function myFunction() 
{
  if(count%10 == 0)
  {
      window.open("http://www.facebook.com/shawnikraghav");
   }
   else
   {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = count;
   }
   count = count + 1;
 
}
`

Comment: If counter reach 60, the condition while is not satisfied anymore, and it will do nothing. If you want to reset the counter, you can add the condition to check the counter >= 60, then set counter back to 1.

Comment: If my answer is useful for you, please check as the it as the answer

Comment: I tried this code -

`var count = 1;

function myFunction() 
{
 while(count <= 60)
 {
  if(count%10 == 0)
  {
      window.open("http://www.facebook.com/shawnikraghav");
   }
   else
   {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = count;
   }
   count = count + 1;
 }
}
`
But it is not incrementing one by one. It just opens all the tabs at once and show the counter display at 59. When it reaches 60, I want it to show maximum counter value reached.

Comment: Oh, I corrected it, the increase of counter should be out of while, please try it

Comment: You mean this -

`var count = 1;

function myFunction() 
{
 while(count <= 60)
 {
  if(count%10 == 0)
  {
      window.open("http://www.facebook.com/shawnikraghav");
   }
   else
   {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = count;
   }
 }
 count = count + 1;
}
`

It is not working either. It hangs my browser for some reason and script just stops working.

Comment: At the first click, the while condition is true and it make the infinite loop. I correct to combine the conditions `(count%10 == 0) && (count < 60)`. Or you can replace the `while` condition by `if`

Comment: Sweeeeet...!!!!!! Completely works. But still the counter keep on running.

Comment: Yes, it's depend on you. If you want to reset, just put `count = 0` in `else`.

Comment: You're welcome, please upvote for me to get full reputation.

Answer (score 0):

try by this way

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var count = 1;  
  $('button.counter').click(function myFunction() {

    while(count <=60) {
      if(count%10 == 0) {
        window.open("http://www.facebook.com/shawnikraghav");
      }
      count = count + 1;
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: Hi, replace while by if